# REST и безопастность

Tags: java, rest

Проблема в следующем, юзер-1 генерирует свое проперти и получает свою карточку в профиле с рестом http://site/#/property/17746. Юзер-2 перебором (подбором) id может посмотреть все проперти даже не свои, что крайне плохо.

Подскажите пожалуйста как организовать правильно безопасность рестов, что бы юзеры не могли подставлять и перебирать id в ссылках?

Comment: Вместо числового id использовать UUID?

Comment: Надо просто проверять в контроллере права текущего юзера и отвечать 403-й ошибкой, если юзер не имеет прав на доступ к запрашиваемым данным.

Comment: 17746 - id в базе, поэтому нет возможности с UUID

Comment: sergey-gornostaev - все юзеры с одинаковыми правами. Имеется ввиду что бы они не лазили друг у друга по пропертям (карточкам)

Comment: @GoodWin сделайте авторизацию ну и там уже если нет доступа выдавайте `403`

Comment: Tsyklop - авторизация есть, проект сделанный на jhipster, spring boot.

Comment: насколько будет правильным в вызове реста предварительно делать запрос что-то типа - если (id_user имеет такой id_property в базе) - шуруй смотри, если false -> получай 403. Минусы - надо в каждый рест-метод а их много. Или это очередной велосипед и есть решение проще и универсальней?

Comment: @GoodWin вполне нормальное решение. Но. Не надо пугаться того что это будет в каждом рест-методе - Вынесете это в отдельный метод и просто вызывайте его в нужном месте. Еще как вариант сделать фильтр который будет смотреть принадлежит ли проперти или нет, если нет то `403` и так не надо везде проверять.

Comment: Вам надо доставать из security контекста текущего юзера и проверять принадлежит ли ему карточка.

Comment: @Tsyklop, с фильтром идея мне нравится, спасибо! попробуем ее реализовать. Странно, что jhipster этого не предусмотрел, наверное..